# How to save the image of a node to the custom directory programmatically?

Tags: 7, media

I have a cck image field and I have the "uploads" directory in the files folder.

I want the images of these nodes are saved to the directory with the name of the node id and then the image file. Suppose if the node id is 4 then the image should be saved to the following directory.

```
files/uploads/4/filename
```

the directory with the name of "4" should be created programmatically.

Which hook should I use for this and how to achieve this? Any one who have some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use following module https://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths . then you can add tokens for it .
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use [File (Field) Paths](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) which supports Drupal 7..

Project page says

> The File (Field) Paths module extends the default functionality of
>   Drupal's core Upload module, the FileField module and many other File
>   Upload modules by adding the ability to use node tokens in destination
>   paths and filenames.
>
> In simple terms, File (Field) Paths allows you to automatically sort
>   and rename your uploaded files using token based replacement patterns
>   to maintain a nice clean filesystem.

Comment: Just a warning - that module is _really_ buggy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Upload path](https://drupal.org/project/uploadpath) module:

> After operating for some time, a website may build up thousands of files in inside the files folder. This uploadpath module allows you to keep the files in the files folder neatly organized in subfolders. It can also allow you to automatically rename uploaded files based on file description or node title.

The module uses the [Token](https://drupal.org/project/token) module for specifying path patterns. It is relatively a small module and you can take a look at its code to get a hint of how it achieves this.